# What does "Compound Tense" mean?

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, past-perfect, perfect-aspect

I have problems with learning about "Compound Tenses".

Please help me.

Comment: The best address would be to visit "English Language Learners", the sister platform for "English Language & Usage".

Comment: sorry, here is the link: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NamSandStorm Thank you. I will try that for my next questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'compound' tense is one which employs an auxiliary word, such as have. The Present is a simple tense 'I go', the past is also simple 'I went', but the Perfect is compound 'I have gone'. 'Have' is the auxiliary. Some compound tenses have two-word auxiliaries such as the Future Perfect 'I shall have gone'.